# Want to keep data on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on page and want to refresh it after short interval.
after each one minute the page should be refresh.
the code i'm using is

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60000">
```

it is working fine, refreshing page after every 1 minute.
when this page is called it loads a datatable.
i want to keep datatable in a variable after first attempt and want to use it for further 4 attempts.
i have used ViewState but it didn't worked.
i do not want to use session as well.is there any other options ?

Comment: Did you enabled enabledViewstate at page level?

Comment: No let me do it. thanks Dalorzo

Comment: I tried  <% Page.EnableViewState = true; %> but did't worked.

Comment: store your datatable in session and retrive it whenever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have figured it out by changing scenario.I have added a class i.e `remainingtime` with each `<td class="remainingtime">` for that specific column.

```
 <script>
    var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
        $("td.remainingtime").each(function () {
            var current = parseInt($(this).text());
            current = current - 5;
            $(this).text(current);
        });
    }, 6000);
</script>
```

it fulfills my requirement. thank you guys for your contributions.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewState` can't be used in your situation because it is not posting to the same page. It's a new request for the same page.

As far I know you need to keep it in `session`. Other wise use `Page caching`  Technique.

```
<%@ OutputCache duration="10" varybyparam="None" %>
```

Add it below page directive it will cache the page. **But the problem is it will be same for all the users**

More detail about caching
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06bh14hk(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06bh14hk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't this contradict the desire behavior of refreshing?

Comment: I don't agree with you. I thing it will be a new request from a server rather than a page refresh. Le me create an example.

Comment: Shekhar i want to show count down timer for each task assign to employee that how many minutes left to complete this task. can you please suggest me some other scenario ?

Comment: I think this can be done using jQuery and web method. Call the jquery method after a interval and maintain the ticker form jquey as well

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="foo.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.DemoPages.foo" 
 ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>
```